# Create indicator variable based on multiple lags or based on previous N rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for more scalable techniques to create indicator variables based on multiple lags. Below you will find a reproducible example showing the desired new variable `in_prev_3` -- which means there was at least one `TRUE` found in the previous three records/rows. While this works, it does not scale well to large values of N (e.g. 15, 30, 45, etc.) nor is it flexible.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(4)
df <- data_frame(
  id = 1:20,
  bool = as.logical(rbinom(20, 1, 0.2))
)

df %>%
  mutate(last_3 = lag(bool, 3) + lag(bool, 2) + lag(bool, 1),
         in_prev_3 = last_3 > 0)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>       id bool  last_3 in_prev_3
#>    <int> <lgl>  <int> <lgl>    
#>  1     1 FALSE     NA NA       
#>  2     2 FALSE     NA NA       
#>  3     3 FALSE     NA NA       
#>  4     4 FALSE      0 FALSE    
#>  5     5 TRUE       0 FALSE    
#>  6     6 FALSE      1 TRUE     
#>  7     7 FALSE      1 TRUE     
#>  8     8 TRUE       1 TRUE     
#>  9     9 TRUE       1 TRUE     
#> 10    10 FALSE      2 TRUE     
#> 11    11 FALSE      2 TRUE     
#> 12    12 FALSE      1 TRUE     
#> 13    13 FALSE      0 FALSE    
#> 14    14 TRUE       0 FALSE    
#> 15    15 FALSE      1 TRUE     
#> 16    16 FALSE      1 TRUE     
#> 17    17 TRUE       1 TRUE     
#> 18    18 FALSE      1 TRUE     
#> 19    19 TRUE       1 TRUE     
#> 20    20 FALSE      2 TRUE
```

Created on 2018-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Can you test if this gives you your desired result: `library(zoo); dplyr::lag(rollapplyr(data = df$bool, width = 3, FUN = any, fill = NA), 1)`

Comment: @markus looks like it (if you also use `align = "right"`! might also try something similar with `tibbletime::rollify`

Comment: Glad it worked. `rollapplyr` is short for `rollapply(..., align = "right")`.

Comment: Missed the little `r` -- there's a [nice article](http://www.business-science.io/business-science-labs/2018/05/31/backtesting-quantopian-zipline-tibbletime-furrr-flyingfox.html) if you're interested in seeing how to apply this type of technique to multiple windows and parallelize with `furrr`.